# Golang gorilla mux not found handler doesn't work correct

Tags: go, http-status-code-404, gorilla, mux

I'm writing a web server and I've got Not Found Handler function.
All the Handle functions like login, registration, view page are working correctly.
I also have such line: `router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(Handlers.NotFoundHandler)`
Handlers is my package including next code:

```
func NotFoundHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //title has to be 404.html
    title := config.Page404
    title = config.WebAppex + title

    fmt.Println("title: " + title)

    /*HERE IS QUESTION LINE*/
    r = http.NewRequest("GET", config.Page404, nil)

    fmt.Println(r.URL.Path)

    logger.Info("Sending... ", title)

    //load page
    p, err := loadPage(title)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("ERROR : ", err.Error())
        p, _ := loadPage(config.Page404)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", p.body) //wired way to send HTML page
        return                       //just return because of printing dry p.body
    }

    //serve it
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p.dir)
    logger.Info(p.dir, " has been sent")
}
```

So the problem is: If I try going to localhost:8080/nothing, then I get my nice Page404
But if I go to localhost:8080/nothing/nothing or localhost:8080/nothing/nothing/nothing and etc, I get dry 404.html without any CSS. So I thought that problem is request, so I create new with the way of "/404.html" (it's config.Page404), but nothing changed. I read about gorilla mux Subrouter, bit It may help to exclude only localhost:8080/nothing, but I need all the cases. So is there any ways to exclude all the not existing pages?

UPD: My loadPage function:

```
func loadPage(title string) (*page, error) {
    logger.Info("Trying to load", title)
    //writing from title to body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(title)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &page{dir: config.HOMEDIR + title, body: body}, nil
}

type page struct {
    dir  string
    body []byte
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably serving your 404 page with a relative CSS stylesheet path, which will obviously fail when serving it from a nested page like `/nothing/nothing/nothing`.

Either use the `<base>` tag to get absolute links everywhere, or redirect your request to the wanted page.

Comment: Thank you, somewhy I didn't know about base tag
You made me able to sleep this night :)